# How to slice multiindex dataframe with list of labels on one level

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

MultiIndex dataframes are very powerful but personally I think there is no enough (clear) documentations on it, specially for different type of slicing...
Here is my question:

**How to slice a multi-indexed dataframe just on one level with a list of labels?**
Please help me if you have a solution (**without reseting indexes and converting the dataframe to single level index! Which is obvious and not efficient**)

For example, we have following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(10))
df['id'] = pd.Series(range(10,20))
df['name'] = [f'name_{id}' for id in range(10,20)]
df['price'] = np.random.rand(df.index.size)
df['date'] = pd.date_range('20200310', '20200319')
df = df.set_index(['id', 'date'])
df
```

[image]

Slicing on one label is working just fine:

```
df.xs('2020-03-10', level='date', drop_level=False)
```

[image]

But how can we slice on a list of labels on that level?

```
df.xs(('2020-03-10', '2020-03-11', '2020-03-12'), level='date', drop_level=False)
```

This leads to an exception:

[image]

However Python doc says that "key" parameter could be a tuple as well:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html

[image]

Comment: I have been observing on stackoverflow that even good questions do not get upvotes. Neither by people who've answered, nor by people who upvote answers. Due credit must be given to the questioner who ensures that their will be answers for people who come seeking them in the future. I have upvoted both the useful question and the useful answer. Thank you op.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For filter by multiple values use [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) with [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
a = df[df.index.get_level_values('date').isin(('2020-03-10', '2020-03-11', '2020-03-12'))]
print (a)
                  name     price
id date                         
10 2020-03-10  name_10  0.557772
11 2020-03-11  name_11  0.122315
12 2020-03-12  name_12  0.775976
```

> However Python doc says that "key" parameter could be a tuple as well:

Tuple is possible use, but working differently - you can select by both labels like:

```
b = df.xs((10, '2020-03-10'), drop_level=False)
print (b)
name      name_10
price    0.348808
Name: (10, 2020-03-10 00:00:00), dtype: object

c = df.xs((10, '2020-03-10'), level=('id','date'), drop_level=False)
print (c)
                  name     price
id date                         
10 2020-03-10  name_10  0.239876
```

Like @yatu mentioned, another solution with `IndexSlice` is with `:` for all first levels and last `:` for all columns:

```
df = df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, ['2020-03-10', '2020-03-11', '2020-03-12']], :]
print (df)
                  name     price
id date                         
10 2020-03-10  name_10  0.557488
11 2020-03-11  name_11  0.592082
12 2020-03-12  name_12  0.547747
```

Comment: Ahh I see what I was missing. Great!

Comment: @jezrael:
I confirm that's kind of solution I was looking for, thank you.
I knew get_level_values method but I didn't think of using it with isin. In fact here I just gave a sample. Practically I just have a date_start and date_end that I want to use to filter. So inspiring by your answer, I can simply do:

df[d >= date_start and d <= date_end for d in df.index.get_level_values('date')]]

Answer (score 4):

The use of tuples when accessing multiindex is meant to address the different levels/hierarchy. Tuples are meant for this use, not as a form of passing multiple items within the same hierarchy/level. For multiple selections within the same level you need to use some other functions such as the one [Jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60525559/how-to-slice-multiindex-dataframe-with-list-of-labels-on-one-level/60525795#60525605).

```
dates = ['2020-03-10', '2020-03-11', '2020-03-12']
filtered_df = df[df.index.get_level_values('date').isin(dates)]
```

Comment: I am quoting your answer and adding explanation regarding the behavior of the function and why passing tuples in `xs` in the way OP is doing it leads to an error.

Comment: You only say "Tuple is possible use, but working differently " not explanation. Different how? Why? You can copy my paragraph and edit your answer, I will delete it. I just wanted to add some lines regarding why using tuples to select multiple values in the same level leads to an error.

Comment: Your answer is THE answer, I just wanted to add some extra information :) +1

Comment: I still thinking what should be best if another answer improve some answer, but honestly not idea how processes. Maybe meta should help what do.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slight variation from the answer provided by @jezrael.

You can use `loc()`  combined with `slice(None)` like this:

```
dates = ['2020-03-10', '2020-03-11', '2020-03-12']

df.loc[(slice(None), dates), :]


id  date        name    price
10  2020-03-10  name_10 0.36806
11  2020-03-11  name_11 0.20436
12  2020-03-12  name_12 0.00443
```

The first argument in `.loc` is a tuple that selects rows in the MultiIndex. `slice(None)` gets all the values from the first level `id`.
The list `dates` filters keys in the second level `date`. The second argument `:` selects all columns.

In the [Pandas Documentation - MultiIndex - Advanced Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index) you can find:

> It is important to note that tuples and lists are not treated identically in pandas when it comes to indexing. Whereas a tuple is interpreted as one multi-level key, a list is used to specify several keys. Or in other words, tuples go horizontally (traversing levels), lists go vertically (scanning levels).